# Python Pandas : How to pass Dataframe as parameters to pd.read_sql?

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy

I have a dataframe `data`

```
         A
 0      10
 1      11
```

I am trying to pass each cell as parameters into `pd.read_sql`

```
query = ("select * table_1 where \"CoA_Id\"=%data[0] or \"CoA_Id\" =%data[1] ;")

result = pd.read_sql(query,con=conn,params={'data[0]':data[0],'data[1]':data[1]})

result_df = pd.DataFrame(result)
```

The `Postgres` query works fine though

```
select * table_1 where "CoA_Id" like '%10%' or "CoA_Id" like '%11%' ;
```

I'm pretty sure something is wrong with my python query, cant seem to figure out what exactly it is

Answer (score 0):

You need access value with `loc`

```py
result = pd.read_sql(query,con=conn,params={'data[0]':data.loc[0, 'A'],'data[1]':data.loc[1, 'A']})
```